# Delphi 2010 vertical toolbar

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am using *RAD Studio 2010* on *Windows 10*. Is there any way to create a vertical toolbar for *Delphi* VCL projects? Something similar to what is shown in the attached picture (right side, top to bottom, on main window):

I need selectable items.This mean changing in back color in clicking or when mouse move over it

[image: vertical toolbar with pictured buttons]

Comment: Yes, there are many ways.

Comment: You can put a `TPanel` on the Form, set its `Align` to `alLeft` or `alRight`, set its `BorderStyle` to `bsNone` or its `BevelEdges` to `[]`, set its `Width` as needed, and put whatever you want on top of it.

Comment: To add to @RemyLebeau's almost correct advice (the thing you need to set regarding the border is `BevelOuter = bvNone`), I often use this approach in my software. I have created a custom button control and a custom [vertical toolbar control](https://privat.rejbrand.se/as3buttons.png), but in principle I could do the same with ordinary `TButton` controls placed on a `TPanel`. In fact, it is even possible to use the ancient Win32 `TToolbar` control in vertical mode.

Comment: Almost like @RemyLebeau, but I'd use a `TScrollBox` instead: once the window height becomes too tiny for any reason you're still able to scroll to your favorite button.

Comment: @AmigoJack is [right](https://privat.rejbrand.se/as3buttons2.png). But don't forget that the `TScrollBox` doesnt support mouse wheel scrolling. You need to implement that yourself (but make sure you don't scroll the scroll box if the cursor is above a focused child control with its own scrolling, such as a combo box!).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I did that successfully in D7 (based on [this](https://www.delphipraxis.net/1183452-post2.html)) and it also has caveats when the parent of the `TScrollBox` is not the `TForm`, but instead a `TTabSheet` of a `TPageControl`.

Comment: @AmigoJack: I have actually created a `TScrollBoxEx` control that handles mouse wheel scrolling (conditionally, of course). I think it works even on a tab sheet, but haven't tried it.

Comment: As i shown in above picture there are selectable items with picture in this toolbar.when i move mouse over them background color will change.how can i do it?

Comment: @Hector no, the picture does not show what you now comment. Please choose a picture that actually shows selecting/hovering one button and omit all irrelevant parts. Most comments already gave you component names you could have tried already - why do you still ask "how"?

Comment: Calm down my friend!.ken white already answered exactly what i need.

Comment: @Hector then not accepting his answer is again unreasonable behaviour. I'll downvote this question for missing details, a picture not focusing on the issue and not having edited the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `TListView`. Assign your images to a `TImageList`, and assign that ImageList to the `ListView.LargeImages` property. Add an item for each image you want to display using the `Items` property (or right-click on the ListView and choose `New Item` from the context menu), assigning the proper caption and imageindex for each item. Make sure the `ListView.ViewStyle` is set to `vsIcon`, and the `ListView.ItemOptions.AutoArrange` is set to `True`.

Here's a sample of the result of a quick test app with a few random images I added - just a few 32x32 images in the Win10 style, courtesy of Icons8. It shows the highlighted `Button 3` item as the mouse pointer is hovering over it.

The only drawback to using the `TListView` is that if the dialog is sized so that all items in the ListView aren't visible, the ListView will display a vertical scrollbar automatically. You'll want to make sure that you leave enough space for that scrollbar just in case, or restrict your window's `MinHeight` constraint to prevent it from being resized too small. On the other hand, if you want to display more than one item in each row, it's easily accomodated with the `TListView` - just widen the control to allow more items per row, and the `AutoArrange` property will take care of everything.

[image]

Comment: This is also a good option. But you should set `BorderStyle = bsNone` to get rid of the upper, right, and lower borders. Then you should add a `TShape` or similar to get the left border.

Comment: Thanks Ken,How can i use 64*64 or bigger image for ListView?TImageList just accept 16 and 32 images

Comment: @Hector: Just set the image list's `Width` and `Height` to `64`

Comment: TimageList doesnt accept 64*64 image and convert those to 32*32

Comment: @Hector: I just tried it in Delphi 10.4, and it works perfectly with 64×64 px. Drop a `TImageList` on your form. Set its `Width` and `Height` to `64`. Then add some 64×64 PNG images to it, and use it as the `LargeImages` of the LV. It bet it will work. Notice that you MUST set `Width` and `Height` BEFORE you add any images to the image list.

Comment: A `TListView` always implies focus, which may be an advantage or disadvantage. But its items will never support accelerator keys to trigger them without focus.

Comment: @AmigoJack is absolutely right. Only in certain scenarios is using a list view as a toolbar a good idea. The main example I can think of is in a settings dialog.

Comment: @Hector: I just tested with 10.4 Sydney, and was able to  set the ImageList width and height to 256x256 and load an image of that size into it. Are you setting the width and height before you add the images?

Comment: @AmigoJack: You're right, a listview might or might not be a viable solution, which is why I didn't say that the poster should or had to use it. I just offered it as a possible solution.